# Localizing 'total seconds' of a timespan in .net

Tags: .net, string-formatting, globalization, timespan

I want to format a TimeSpan into its number of seconds, but I would like the conversion to be locale-aware. For example:

```
// NOT FUNCTIONAL but illustrates what I mean
String.Format("{0:0.0s}", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5324)) = "2.5s"
String.Format("{0:0s}", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)) = "120s"
```

I could implement the functionality like this:

```
someTimeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0") + "s"
```

But this assumes that seconds are represented by 's' and that the unit should come after the quantity. It's possible that this is standard across locales, since it's part of SI, but maybe not (for example, even in the US, some units aren't a suffix: 5 dollars is $5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use the locale-aware formatting options for *double* to handle the numeric portion.

```
// "N" is an example format.  Use what your app needs.
value.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Windows localization does not provide any support for localizing abbreviations for things like *second*, so you will have to handle that part yourself.